# how to append some files and skipping first two lines?

Tags: r, file

I have for example 3 text files: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` in a directory. All the files have the same columns names( i.e. the 2 first lines). I want to create a new text file that contains all the data of the 3 files but I don't want to repeat the names of the columns, i.e. *The names of the columns in the new file have to be written only once, in the first two lines*.

I know how to do it with `read.table()` and `write table()`. But is there another option? 
something like... `file.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-existing equivalent of `file.append()` which **also** trims off the first lines  of all but the first file it's passed. But this is R, so you can write a function that does that, as I show below.

Using `readLines()` and `cat()` will output a file that looks more like that produced by `file.append()` than will using `read.table()` and `write.table()`. For large files, it will also be faster.

```
file.trim.append <- function(fnames, outfile) {
    ## Take header lines from first file
    cat(readLines(fnames[1], n = 2), file = outfile, sep = "\n")
    ## Append all but first two lines of each
    lapply(fnames, function(fname) {
        cat(readLines(fname)[-1:-2], file = outfile,
            sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
    })
}

## Try it out
write.table(head(mtcars), file="file1.txt")
write.table(head(mtcars), file="file2.txt")
write.table(head(mtcars), file="file3.txt")
ff <- dir(pattern = "^file[[:digit:]]*.txt")

file.trim.append(ff, "file123.txt")
```

Comment: I would be interested in knowing why using `cat` is safer than `read.table`. Can you expand your comment on this?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik -- Yeah, "safer" is not exactly the right word. What I'm thinking of is situations where `read.table/write.table` aren't really invertible. The fastest way for me to explain what I mean is to have you try this code: `write.table(read.table(text="A B\n10000000000000 0.123456789123456789", header=T), row.names=F)`. Because `cat(readLines())` just reads and writes characters, it won't produce the conversions that result from going from character to numeric (`read.table()`) then back to character (`write.table()`).

Comment: Tank you for answering. But it isn't working exactly like I want. My header is 2 first lines. The names of the columns in the new file have to be written only once. Like this the second line of the header is repeated each time. I don't know how to repair it.

Comment: @Tatiana -- OK, I just now edited it to show you how that'd be done.

Comment: Many Thanks, I didn't know this utilisation of readLines(fname)[-1:-2]

Answer (score 0):

If your data fits in memory, the simplest approach is to read all files, append them rowise and dump the big data frame. I would use plyr which streamlines this:

```
require(plyr)
big_data = ldply(c("file1", "file2", etc), read.table)
write.csv(big_data, file = "bigfile")
```

another solution is to use Bash tools to append the files. See e.g. head tail, and >>. This ofcourse only works under Unix or Mac, or using MinGW or Cygwin under windows. These tools can be called from within R using the system function.